# YUI DataTable get total number records

Tags: cakephp, yui, yui-datatable, yui-datasource

I am new to YUI and I am using YUI 2 Datatable, I would like to alert if the total number of record is more than 4000 and not to render the table.

below is my piece of code.

```
this.myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource("<?php echo $html->url('/parser/dynload').'?params_array_serialized='.$params_array_serialized; ?>");

this.myDataTable = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable("gridbox", myColumnDefs,this.myDataSource, myConfigs);
```

I dont know how to get total number of record. Any one can help in this.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, `this.myDataTable` would have a `getRecordSet()` method which returns a `RecordSet` object which is a where the DataTable stores its data.  The `RecordSet` has a `length` (or perhaps it was `count`?) property or was it `getLength()` method.  Anyway, regardless of the names which I cannot quite remember but the debugger will tell you, the `RecordSet` object is the key to it.

I do remember that the last build of the API docs for YUI went wrong and I believe the `RecordSet` object got accidentally dropped or misplaced so you won't find it there.